# R - subset list data.frames by vector values

Tags: r, list, loops, spatial

I have a list of `SpatialLinesDataFrames` and want to subset the list based on comparing the values to those in a numeric vector.

Specifically, I want to remove list elements that has one of the values contained in the vector in a specific column ('lineID') of the data.frame. Reproducible example:

```
#create list of single-feature SpatialLineDataFrame
library(raster)
l1 <- cbind(c(0,3), c(0,3))
l2 <- cbind(c(0, 13), c(0, 1))
l3 <- cbind(c(0, 24), c(0,22.5))
l4 <- cbind(c(0, 1), c(0,13))
l5 <- cbind(c(0, 6), c(0,6))
Sldf <- spLines(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, attr=data.frame(lineID=1:5))

sldfl <- list()
sldfl[[1]] <- Sldf[1,]
sldfl[[2]] <- Sldf[2,]
sldfl[[3]] <- Sldf[3,]
sldfl[[4]] <- Sldf[4,]
sldfl[[5]] <- Sldf[5,]

#create numeric vector
m <- c(1,3,5,7,10)

#attempt to keep only list elements that are not equal to any 
#of the values contained in vector
final <- list()
for (i in 1:length(sldfl)) {
  for (j in 1:length(m)) {
    if (factor(sldfl[[i]]@data$lineID) != m[j]) {
      final[[i]] <- sldfl[[i]]
    }}}
```

The result of the loop returns the entire original list. What is wrong with my loop?

Comment: Because for each of your polygon lineIDs in the sldfl list there exists at least one value in `m` that is not the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially got two vectors, `ids` and `m`:

```
> ids
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> m
[1]  1  3  5  7 10
```

and are running essentially this:

```
for(i in 1:length(ids)){
 for(j in 1:length(m)){
  if(i != m[j]){
    message("add ",i,j)
  }else{
    message("Not adding ",i,j)
  }
 }
}
```

Run that and you'll see it adds lots of elements because you are testing each ID with every element in `m`, and at least one element of `m` is not in the ID, so that one (and more) get added.

Where what you really seem to want is:

```
for(i in 1:length(ids)){

  if(!(i %in% m)){
    message("add ",i,j)
  }else{
    message("Not adding ",i,j)
  }
 }
```

which prints:

```
Not adding 15
add 25
Not adding 35
add 45
Not adding 55
```

That adds elements with ID 2 and 4 which are the ones not in `m`.

Alternatively, use the base R `Filter` function which reduces a list by a function on a list element:

```
> Filter(function(L){!(L@data$lineID  %in% m)}, sldfl)
[[1]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : lineID 
value       :      2 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 13  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : lineID 
value       :      4
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the solution and explanation